# Toon Water Ripples With Nodes

Tags: node-editor, shaders, geometry-nodes

I have found [this brilliant application of the Geometry Nodes](https://twitter.com/lateasusual_/status/1364305405027975175) in Blender.
It was used for the Alpha Version 2.93

I tried to recreate it, but it is not working (The Water Ripple remain unconscious)

How can I solve this?

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the "Ripple" Nodes that prevent the moving?

Comment: Can you pls share the file, to many nodes for reconstructing them

Answer (score 13):

First of all, congratulations to [Late As Usual](https://twitter.com/lateasusual_) for a very cunning trick, essentially taking a conical sloping view down the Z of a 3D noise texture, to 'thicken' it in the ripple direction. Brilliant and simple.

It's hard to tell what's up with your version.. I don't think we can see your nodes?

Here's an adaptation to GN(Fields):

[image]

A couple of tweaks:

- I've used only the Z component of the vertex color to encode the distance to the nearest coast.. you could use X and Y to encode something else; say, the direction to the nearest coastal point.
- I've divided the distances by the maximum distance, to normalize the range from 0-1. If you're dipping stuff in and out of the water, that should be muted.. it could change the whole range every time that happened.

The `Col`  vertex-color attribute is used in this shader tree:

[image]

.. which is a slight simplification of the one illustrated, but seems to do the trick. The purple driver in the 'Value' node is made by typing  `#frame` into the field.

[image]

[image]

(Blender 3.0b)