# Accidental procedural ripples

Tags: shaders, procedural

Ok so, a long time ago when I was just starting out with Blender, I was following this tutorial about making soup:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yWfeJFJ95gI

At some point during the tutorial I did something in the Shading editor when making the soup part and instead of a wobbly Musgrave texture I got something like ripples (incomplete circles tapering at both ends). Anyway, I got it by accident, I saved it as an asset, stored it in my flash drive along with other shaders and textures and I have not thought about how I managed to get it since.

Cut to several years later, my flash drive broke, I got the majority of my files restored on it, except the whole Asset library I had on it. I've slowly been remaking whatever Assests I remember having on it originally, but then I got completely stumped on those ripples.

I can't seem to recreate them and I definitely don't remember how I managed to make them.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Additional info:

- Yes I remember specifically following THAT tutorial.
- I remember changing 1 or 2 things from that tutorial using the Shader editor.
- I'm pretty sure I didn't use any textures.
- I tried remaking it using the Wave texture in case that was it, but I don't know how to ''divide'' the circles.
- It was a completely flat, 2D procedural shader texture.
- Honestly it doesn't have to be based on the tutorial if anyone has their own similar version.

I've wracked by brain for a while about this and it's just annoying having to wonder what the heck did I do back then. I finally decided to take this issue to the forums in hopes someone has an idea.

For reference, here's a render I did way back when with the ripples in question.

[image: Miso soup]

And here's a picture of the ripple shapes I had in mind

[image: Ripples]

Comment: [This one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243958/35559) may be of interest

Comment: Thank you, but that's not quite what I was looking for...
Honestly I've been playing around and while I'm able to create ripples, I'm having trouble separating the rings, so that they wouldn't be complete 360 circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with two setups. It's not exactly what you have shown but maybe it will point you in the right direction.

Number 1:
[image]

Number 2:
[image]

I prefer the first one because it looks more organic

Comment: Yes, the 1st one is the closest thing to what I had in mind! The structure also feels familiar. Thanks a lot!