# 2d Disney like Water ripple effect

Tags: shaders, 2d

so i am trying to achieve the old disney classics ripples style for a simple animation wher objects will be floating randomly on a a body of water like so [image]

ive been following a tutorial that utilizes dynamic paint and shader nodes to create anime water so i tried tailoring it to my needs and arrived at this.
[image]

can someone help me adjust the nodes so that the ripples appear in one color while the body of water is another while removing the obvious division of colors in the water body. Thanks

Comment: There are some good tutorials on YouTube for this. Have you seen this one? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uOXagWeOAv4

Comment: it uses geometry nodes while im looking for a shder editor solution

Comment: @a-python-script thanks for sharing this *crazy* trick :D

Comment: @EmmaMaina can you add more details or share demo file to your question? How have you set up the DP? Does it use the wave option? Must the water be flat or can it have 3D waves? Are the waves like those of raindrops or more like those of a ship sailing through the water? Should it settle down after a while? -- I also think the shader shown in the tutorial is very useful. Yes, it uses GN for the proximity but you do this with DP, too. The shader will be the same.

Comment: i have setup dynamic paint; no it uses paint option with mesh volume & proximity; no 3d waves please just flat; more of raindrops or falling flowers; yes it should fade; let me check it out and see what i can apply

Comment: Perhaps a variation on [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243958/35559) .. you could use dummy spheres to generate circular ripples. Do you want the outlining, too?