Make beach waves with shading
I have the following scene:


I would like to add a white outline to the water to simulate the foam from the waves clashing into the shore. I was wondering if there was an easier way than needing to texture paint it manually.
I tried using ambient oclussion but every other object on the water, like the bridge, had an effect on it and it didn't even look good really.

If there is no easier way, could anyone recomend some tips or free brushes, so that the foam or the waves look far more interesting, please, as just the outline doesn't really do enough for me.


Possibly related:   https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/243958/35559

That was helpful, thanks!
